# Dynamically adding 1 PolymerElement to another shows in childNodes but not queryable?

Tags: dart, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I have 2 classes i created which *extend* PolymerElement, we can call them:   ElementA, and ElementB.

So, i want to add ElementB to ElementA dynamically, so i was thinking to add it to the onReady call of ElementA as follows:

```
class ElemenetA extends PolymerElement{
  ElementB get _myElement => $["bid"];
  onReady(){
    ElementB item = new ElementB(); //item has an id of "bid"
    Polymer.dom(this).childNodes.add(item);
  }
}
```

So when i visit the Component, each time, it will add a new ElementB to the childNodes.  Its ok, i will resolve this later.

The issue i have bumped into though is that ElementB doesnt render at all and if i try to call a method from it such as *open* like this: `_myElement.open();` it will say `null does not have method open`.

What am i doing wrong to inject a PolymerElement into another?

My overall goal is to pull out a common element in a bunch of other Components and just use a behavior to inject this re-occurring item into the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access elements that are dynamically added using `$[...]`, this works only for elements added statically to the elements HTML. Even when they are inside a `<template is="dom-if">` or `<template is="dom-repeat">` `$[...]` cant be used.

Use instead `$$('#bid')`

Comment: This doesnt seem to work.  Is there anything specific i am missing?

Comment: I don't know. What does "doesn't seem to work" mean exactly? Have you checked the element was added to the DOM in browser devtools?

Comment: when looking at the dev tools, it didnt seem to add anything, so when it tried to reference `$$("#bid")` it returned null.  The exact function i used was: `Polymer.dom(this).childValues.add(_myElement);` Im thinking somehow it failed to add the element to the dom, so it wasnt queryable.

Comment: What is `childValues`? See if there is `Polymer.dom(this).append(_myElement);`

Comment: `Polymer.dom(this)` should return a PolymerDom object, which has a bunch of properties.  See polymer.dom.dart.    It seems that the *append* function requires it to be `this.root` and the parameter to be a Node instead of an PolymerElement.  Is there a way to turn a PolymerEleemnt into a Node?

Comment: Every element is a `Node`. `Node` is a super class of `Element` that also includes `TextNode` or `Comment`, ...

Comment: `Uncaught Unhandled exception:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
#0      JsObject.callMethod (dart:js:1085)
#1      PolymerDom.append (package:polymer_interop/src/polymer_dom.dart:53:31)
#2      Classifications.attached (package:seg_ui/classifications/classifications.dart:75:28)
#3      Function._apply (dart:core-patch/function_patch.dart:7)
#4      Function.apply (dart:core-patch/function_patch.dart:28)
#5      _InstanceMirrorImpl.invoke (package:reflectable/src/reflectable_transformer_based.dart:259:21)`

Comment: What does `print(item)` print (after `ElementB item = new ElementB();`? When you add `ElementB` directly in the HTML, does it show up properly?

Comment: After some tweaks, I now have it in the markup, I just noticed that the ElementB, doesnt seem to have an ID, so i may have to look into an alternate way for accessing it via the getter.

Comment: How do you set the id?

Comment: Yeah, never assigned it in the PolymerElement, but created it in the constructor. haha.   Its weird though, the other properties dont end up setting.   I do:   PolymerElement myElement = new PE();  myElement.property = "test"; and it seems to not assign it.   Do i need to set them via the set method not?  set("myElement.property", "test"); or something?

Comment: `myElement.set('property', 'test')`

Comment: `PaperDialog createDialog(PolymerElement dialog){
    PaperDialog alert = new TwAlert();
    alert.id = dialog.id;
    alert.heading = dialog.title;
    alert.message = dialog.description;
    alert.confirmLabel = dialog.primaryButtonLabel;
    alert.cancelLabel = dialog.alternateButtonLabel;
    alert.confirmFunction = dialog.confirmFunction;
    return alert;
  }`

Comment: Actually I would add a setter that does the `set(...)` and call the setter instead.

Comment: ahh ok.   I wasnt sure if i still needed to call set on this stuff with the dynamic information

Comment: It is now working.   I just did myElement.set("prop", value);

Comment: Great :) . . . . .  .